# Django jquery flot chart multiple series

Tags: django, charts, flot

I use Flot for chart in my Django app. I want to draw every day a chart that has many data series (lines chart). Each day, the serial number could change and I don't know how to handle this with flot. My code is more or less this:

test.py

```
 data_day_1 = [[1,56],[2,65],[3,45]]
 data_day_2 = [[1,45],[2,23],[3,89]]
 return render_to_response('test.html', {'data_day_1': data_day_1,
                                         'data_day_2': data_day_2,
                                         },
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

test.html

```
 <div class="portlet-body">
     <div id="site_statistics" class="chart"></div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var data1 = [];
 {% for x, y in data_day_1 %}
 data1.push([{{x}},{{y}}])
 {% endfor %} 

 var data2 = [];
 {% for x, y in data_day_2 %}
 data2.push([{{x}},{{y}}])
 {% endfor %} 

 $(function () {    
    var Options = { lines: {show: true},                
                          }
        $.plot($("#site_statistics"), 
        [{data: data1,
      color: "#454d7d",
      points: {show: true},
      label: "data_day_1", 
      },
     {data: data2,
      color: "#454d7d",
      points: {show: true},
      label: "data_day_2", 
      }
     ],Options);
});
```

Another day I might have another set (eg data_day_3) and do not know how to do. How can I do to manage the transfer of data and the design of the new line dynamically? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode your data in json:

```
from django.utils import simplejson as json

data_all_days = [
   {'label': 'Day 1',
    'data': [[1, 4], [1,8], [9, 8]],
    'color': '#000',
   },
   {'label': 'Day 2',
    'data':...,
    'color': ...,
    },
   ...]
render_to_response( ... {'charts': json.dumps(data_all_days)})
```

and in the template just use the json as javascript code:

```
var chart_data = {{ charts|safe }};

$.plot($('#site_statistics'), chart_data);
```

You'll have the structure of `data_all_days` in your js code and will parse it with a cycle.
Read on [jquery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

While running this code, open it in Chrome or FireFox and open developer tools (Ctrl+I or F12) and see the debug console, it will show if there are errors in the JavaScript.

`|safe` is a template filter to prevent code from being html-quoted.

Comment: I tried with this code but doesn't work, The graph is not seen ... I added only "option" variable in the code. What can be the problem? thanks

Comment: EDIT: now it works bat show only one serie... I'm going crazy. I changed this: ...,[{ data: val.data, label: val.label }], Options.. If I don't put [] the graph don't show.

Comment: Oh, it was my mistake, you don't need a cycle there, right, actually you can just make the structure on the server side.